# How to ignore spatial index?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

When i do Schema Compare in Visual Studio i see that spatial index in table was changed and this changes will included in generated script. But i do not want see this changes in my script. It's becouse i have a several databases and each database have own spatial index in tables.
In spatial index changed only BBox part:

```
BOUNDING_BOX = (XMAX = 500000, XMIN = 300000, YMAX = 1600000, YMIN = 1400000),
```

It's possible exclude spatial index from schema compare?

Comment: I don't think you can tell it to not compare certain objects, but isn't there an option to skip items when generating the actual deployment script?